# Can I reference the current EA.DocumentGenerator context from a Custom Script Fragment?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I've written a script to generate certain process documentation. It works, but it has to replicate a lot of the built-in documentation functionality.

It would be "nicer" to call this script from within a custom script fragment, so as to enable the core documentation processing to be used, but to generate the extra data from a custom script fragment.

(The custom fragment isn't sufficiently functional in-and-of itself, since it doesn't allow appear to allow optional variables or bookmarking to hide unused sections, and what I'm trying to do requires several variations in format).

In order to do that, I think I need to get access to the current instance of EA.DocumentGenerator to enable me to call the various methods to add elements and data within the custom fragment. Is this possible and if so how do I obtain it?

If it's not possible, is there any other way of partially scripting document generation, rather than having to effectively re-write the whole document generation process as a script?

Comment: I usually go the scripting route myself. Variations in format are best achieved by checking element stereotypes and/or tagged values.

Comment: In a comment on the Sparx forum (http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1440140359) it looks like this could be in the next version. Here's hoping...

Comment: I've documented my approach in this article on my website: [Tutorial: Generate complex documents from Enterprise Architect with a two-step semi-automated approach](http://bellekens.com/2015/11/12/tutorial-generate-complex-documents-from-enterprise-architect-with-a-two-step-semi-automated-approach/)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to get hold of the "current" DocumentGenerator -- if indeed EA uses DocumentGenerator internally, which is in no way guaranteed.

The only other way to create complex documents is to use virtual documents, which are documented in the Help file under Reporting -- Document Reports -- Virtual Documents. With this approach, target document structures are essentially modelled, although the same RTF templates are used for the generation.

Comment: I use this approach of virtual document, even for the most complex documents. I do however create the virtual document and the different sections using a script.